# Arguments as global variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use a global variable for using as argument for two or more functions:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     function foo(x){
        var z = '#'+ x ;
        // use function bar(y,z) insde;
     }
     function bar(y,z){
       //
     }

    });
```

In practice, bar function cant see the z argument. Is there any way to define "z" as a global variable?

Thanks

Comment: To make a variable global, remove the 'var' in front of it.  Also, what are you trying to do with `return function bar(y,z);`?  That's a syntax error.

Comment: @Rocket, a long day without food for only a "var" ! Thanks alot!!

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you want `z` to be global? And if it's global, then why would you accept it as a parameter if `bar` can just access it directly? I don't suggest using global variables. Closures are generally a better way to control variable scope.

Comment: TheNone: Do not solve this by removing `var`. It isn't a good practice. You should always use `var` when defining a variable. Use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608770/arguments-as-global-variables-in-javascript/4608810#4608810) from [@Šime Vidas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/425275/sime-vidas) instead.

Comment: @Rocket: It isn't good to advise someone to leave `var` off. The practice can end up being the source of hard to trace errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var z;

    function foo(x) {
        z = '#' + x;
    }

    function bar(y) {
        // use z
    }

});
```

As you can see, the z variable is local to the ready handler. The foo and bar functions have access to it.

However, this may or may not be the best solution. That depends on how the foo and bar functions are used (where are they called from).

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this. Make the variable global, or pass it as a parameter.

```
var z;
function foo(x) {
  z = '#' + x;
}
function bar(y,z){

}
```

or

```
function foo(x) {
  var z = '#' + x;
  var result = bar(y,z);
}
....
```